# i got ibfk_5 when trying input forreign key to table

Tags: java, mysql, foreign-keys

I have structure table like this.

[alt text http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/3315/stucture.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/3315/stucture.png)

the problem is :

When i want to input data to "index" table. I got this error.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails
>   (`test`.`index`, CONSTRAINT
>   `index_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`b_FK`)
>   REFERENCES `b` (`Id_B`))

When i remove the relation index and b. it's working fine.

i using same way for a_Fk, and c_Fk. but only b_FK which have problem.

Anyone know how to solve this? thx b4

FYI : i using java, net bean 6.8, mySql (Xampp V.3.2.0.1)

Comment: can you add the "show create table ..."  output? That way it's easier to see which indices and (possibly unique) keys have been defined.

Comment: Maybe you do not have a corresponding data row in test.b ? For a foreign key to work you must already have the data in a,b and c before you insert into index.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting a value in column b_FK of table index that does not exist in table b, Id_B column.

Perhaps you should make sure to insert data in tables a, b, and c and only then in `index`.
Also, if your b_FK column is something like `not null default 0`, change it to accept null for whenever you need to save a row to `index` table with an empty b_FK.

As extraneon said in his comment, it always help to provide more data, we can't guess these details ourselves.